# Submitting canceling form submit from inside second function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to stop my form from submitting when the confirmation message is cancelled, but how can I cancel my form’s submission from inside the `each()`?

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var inputs = $(this).find('input:checked');
    inputs.each(function() {
        var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
        if(inputId != undefined && inputId.substring(0, 8) == 'inputName') {
            var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?");
            if (r == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                // This doesn't stop the form submit
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event argument that’s passed to event listeners instead; it has [a method named `preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) that stops the default action from being performed.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    var inputs = $(this).find('input:checked');

    inputs.each(function () {
        var inputId = this.id;

        if (inputId != undefined && inputId.substring(0, 8) == 'inputName') {
            var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?");

            if (!r) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```